# How to add events to Google Calendar through FullCalendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

I've been searching for a long time now, but can't seem to find an answer.

My FullCalendar is linked up with Google Calendar. I can see my events. I followed every step from this guide (http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/).

However, when I add an event, it doesn't add it to Google Calendar.
Neither can I move the GoogleCalendar-events inside the FullCalendar.

Is two-ways communication supported?
If so, where can I find some references?

Sorry for your time. Thanks in advance.